# Grouping List<CustomerOrder> into Map<Gender, Money>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
public class CustomerOrder {

    private final Gender gender;
    private final Order order;

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

}

public class Order {

    private final long orderAmount;

    public long getOrderAmount() {
        return orderAmount;
    }

}
```

I'd like to achieve the java streaming equivalent of:

```
SELECT Gender, SUM(orderAmount) FROM orders
GROUP BY Gender;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I over simplified the problem - CustomerOrder contains an Order, which contains the orderAmount

I have managed to get to `Map<Gender, List<Long>>` by something like:

```
Map<Gender, List<Long>> map = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomerOrder::getGender))
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, edited the question with what I've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomerOrder::getGender,
            Collectors.summingLong(CustomerOrder::getOrderAmmount));
```

**EDIT**

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomerOrder::getGender,
            Collectors.summingLong(co -> co.getOrder().getAmmount()));
```

I did not compile this, but should work (with minor replacements).

Comment: I've edited the problem, can you update your answer accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not quite correct. stream::collect method either takes one or three parameters, not two. What you're looking for is `stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomerOrder::getGender, Collectors.summingInt( co -> co.getOrder().getAmount()))`, that is Collectors.groupingBy with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), which has 3 arguments:

- A mapping function to produce keys
- A mapping function to produce values
- A merge function that is used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key

Here's the code:

```
Map<Gender, Long> result = customerOrders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        CustomerOrder::getGender,
        co -> co.getOrder().getOrderAmount(),
        Long::sum));
```

If you need to specify the type of the returned map, i.e. if you need the map to be ordered by gender, you could use the 4-argument overload of `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<Gender, Long> result = customerOrders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        CustomerOrder::getGender,
        co -> co.getOrder().getOrderAmount(),
        Long::sum,
        TreeMap::new));
```